# CLOCK_REALTIME, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW values.

Tags: c, time, clock

I ran basic snippet of code.

```
void emptyFunction(){
};

int main(){

const int conversion = 1000000000;
unsigned long long func_sum = 0;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &funcTimeStart);
emptyFunction();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &funcTimeEnd);

func_sum=((funcTimeEnd.tv_sec*nanoConversion)+funcTimeEnd.tv_nsec)-((funcTimeStart.tv_sec*nanoConversion)+funcTimeStart.tv_nsec);
```

This is to test the time it takes to run an empty function.

I run each of them 10 times and my values are as followed:

If I used:

CLOCK_REALTIME - my value is 57-108 nanoseconds

CLOCK_MONOTONIC - my value is 39-98 nanoseconds

CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW - my value is 282-487 nanoseconds

CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID - my value is 662-1049 nanoseconds

From my understanding, CLOCK_REALTIME uses the wall clock time to measure, whereas CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID uses the time the CPU is running the code. Then wouldn't CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID always be have a lower number? Why is it not the case here?

Comment: Did you disable interrupts? The time you measure contains also ISR events. I think this will be for all the measure. Furthermore, if you use to call a function that does nothing the compiler may don't generate the call (especially when you use optimizations)

Comment: You did not measure the execution time of an empty function, you measured the amount of overhead in the clock_gettime() function implementation.  Sure, it depends on what clockid_t you pass.

Answer (score 0):

You did not measure the execution time of an empty function, you measured the amount of overhead in the clock_gettime() function implementation. Sure, it depends on what clockid_t you pass. – Hans Passant